# Node SOAP WSDL Request Incomplete (only some chunks)

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, soap, request

I’m having trouble accessing a SOAP web service using the [node-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) npm module.

Here’s what I’m trying:

```
var url = 'https://ws-uat.ewinerysolutions.com/2.00/EWSWebServices.asmx?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(client.describe());
}
```

This doesn’t error, but does log an empty object. Examining `client` shows that the returned XML gets truncated, which would in turn keep the node-soap module from building a proper client. The XML’s exact length fluctuates in amounts of 16348 bytes. If I move the WSDL so it’s referencing a local file then `client.describe()` performs as expected, and calls to the web service are also available. However, longer responses to such requests also truncate in similar fashion. This has led me to believe that something is closing the connection before all chunks of data have been received, so I checked out the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm module (also packaged with node).

In an attempt to isolate the issue, I have tried [retrieving the WSDL using *only* the request module](https://tonicdev.com/56be371d273d6b0c00c70599/56c60f5afc5fed0d00f34c2b):

```
var request = require('request');

var body = "";

request.get('https://ws-uat.ewinerysolutions.com/2.00/EWSWebServices.asmx?wsdl')
    .on('data', function(data){
        body += data;
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);  
    })
```

[See a live version of this](https://tonicdev.com/56be371d273d6b0c00c70599/56c60f5afc5fed0d00f34c2b) that returns a truncated XML body.

I have had this working before with these very same libraries, and just to be sure I’ve tried running the same program with a sequence of older versions of dependency libraries.

I’m also still quite new to this stuff, so any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [New open issue on the request module repo](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2093), as this issue doesn’t manifest when you use node version 0.10.41.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add connection: 'keep-alive' to the request header. In the node-soap library this can be set directly in lib/http.js:46.